# The version 1.3.0 a-frame does not work in WebView on Android when switching to VR mode

Tags: android, kotlin, aframe

The version 1.3.0 a-frame does not work in WebView on Android 7 when switching to VR mode. Black screen. Without VR mode, it works. Version 1.0.1 works fine both in VR mode and without VR mode. No one knows if something needs to be done in WebView for the new version 1.3.0, or is this a-frame not working?
Why does everything work in version 1.0.1, but does not work in VR mode in version 1.3.0?

When switching to VR mode, it shows this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eppJE.jpg

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: Added an image with an error in the description from the console.

Comment: The question is closed. Android WebView does not support Web XR and most likely will never support it.